# OnSelectionChange is not triggering while using selectionProps to checked the check box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

I am making my check-box checked based on condition. It's showing checked in UI but it's not triggering onSelectionChange method no it's working with normal checked. Kindly provide if anyone has a solution

I tried everything including adding onChange method to trigger the onChange method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Hello, please provide some of your code for review.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.